# Yii, controllers in different subfolders

Tags: php, yii

I have folder hierarchy

```
---protected
------...
------controller
---------admin
------------OneController.php
------------TwoController.php
---------user
------------ThreeController.php
------------FourController.php
```

also i add them in main.php as

```
'import' => array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.forms.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.fetcher.*',
    'application.controllers.admin.*',
    'application.controllers.user.*', ...
```

add route for admin

```
    'urlManager' => array(
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'rules' => array(
            // ...
            'admin' => 'admin/one/index',
```

but this doesn't work, can you help to deal with it? I want do simply routes to subfoldered controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax of rule is wrong. Try to use

```
'rules' => array(
    'admin' => 'admin/one/index'
)
```

Comment: it was simple mistake on posting example

Answer (score 0):

I Found solution. My mistake was on controller, I have default (old) OneController in /protected/controllers that's why routes give me 'old' data, when I change name of (old) OneController, trouble gone. And after that route give me new one from /protected/controllers/admin/OneController.

it was like this one

```
---protected
------...
------controller
---------OneController.php <-- this gives wrong data even error because of routes
---------admin
------------OneController.php
------------TwoController.php
---------user
------------ThreeController.php
------------FourController.php
```